# How to filter google-maps markers

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-cloud-firestore, markers

I don't know how to solve the following problem. I have integrated a Google map in my Flutter app, on which various markers are displayed, which get their coordinates from a firestore. Each marker should represent a car. Every car has different information in the Firebase, such as license plate number, color, age, make of car and so on and so on. The problem or the goal is that I want to display, if the user enters the car brand such as BMW in the text field above the Google maps,  only the markers which have `brand: 'BMW'` in their firestore document. ***To summerize:*** When a user writes a brand in the textfield, only markers with `brand: '*textfield-imput*'` should be presented. I don't know how I can achieve my goal ...

Do I have to download all the data beforehand and then filter them or do I have to filter them beforehand and then download them? Can someone recommend tutorials / blog posts and share the link? Or can someone explain to me how best to proceed?

Here is a screenshot of one firestore document:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 GoogleMap(
   myLocationEnabled: true,
   myLocationButtonEnabled: _,
   onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
   onCameraMoveStarted: () {  
   },
  onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) async {
  
   
  },
  onCameraIdle: () async {
   
  },
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: ,
    zoom: _appStateProvider.zoom,
  ),
  markers: //this markers,
  polylines: _,
  scrollGesturesEnabled:,
)
```

visit: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: I have intigrated google maps in my application, that is noct the problem, the problem is how to filter the markers

Comment: You can write the filter action in any function. and then you can add that function markers. It also explains the filter feature of googlemap packagen.

Comment: can you send me the link where the filter feature of the g-maps is explained?